# Is there a “Film -> Transparent” Layer-specific option?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I know about the Transparent setting that makes a scene render with the background as transparent, but I’d like to have a layer-specific version of this option for single scene compositing. Does such an option exist?

Comment: Good question, I just moved my last comment from the other question here: Just a quick idea, maybe it's possible to put an object in the background which shows the same as the background, but can also be turned off in the other layer?

Comment: I've tried a very large sphere using an _Environment Texture_ set to "Equirectangular" to surround the whole scene, but this is just an approximation of the real background. And the more you move the camera around the worse and weird the result can get.

Comment: Using a very large object set to holdout shader in the background and setting it to only render on camera light paths and be transparent otherwise should work, no ?

Comment: @Gorgious Either I cannot setup correctly what you mean or it is not working. Let's say I have a scene with a background, and I want to see the background in the render. And I have two view layers, one shows different objects than the other, but in the compositor I want to alpha over the second layer over the first. Is this possible with view layers instead of scenes? Or else: is it possible with what you mean with the holdout?

Comment: Yeah I didn't test that and it may very well be simpler with custom view layers and environment in compositing. Hard to say more without the actual setup from OP

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I wrecked my brain before but the solution can sometimes be quite simple. Of course my example scene has no need for this setup, it's just to show the workflow itself.

Let's say I need one view layer with a transparent background because I want to alpha it over another view layer. The final composite of the image should show the background, but I cannot render one view layer with *Film* > *Transparent* and the other without in a single render.

The solution is, setting it to *Transparent* and enabling *Environment* in the *View Layer Properties* under *Passes* > *Light* > *Other* > *Environment*.

In the *Compositor* just use another *Alpha Over* node to put the *Env* output of the *Render Layer* node below the renders.

[image: alpha over background]

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.90 you can use a driver to set properties per view layer:

[image]

1. Enable 'Auto Run Python Scripts' *(Preferences > Save & Load > Auto Run...)*
2. Add a new text document in the *Text Editor*, copy the following code into the document, change `View Layer 1` to your desired name and run the script:

   ```
   def is_view_layer(depsgraph: bpy.types.Depsgraph) -> bool:
       print(f"depsgraph={depsgraph.mode} VL={depsgraph.view_layer.name}")
       return "View Layer 1" in depsgraph.view_layer.name

   bpy.app.driver_namespace['is_view_layer'] = is_view_layer
   ```
3. Add a driver to the property and add `is_view_layer(depsgraph)` to the expression

[Release Notes: Dependency Graph passed to Drivers](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Animation-Rigging#Dependency_Graph_passed_to_Drivers)